# What are the best practice for domain names (dev, staging, production)?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cloudflare, paas, deis

With the rise of containers, Kuberenetes, 12 Factor etc, it has become easier to replicate an identical environment across dev, staging and production. However, what there appears to be no common standard to domain name conventions.

As far as I can see it, there are two ways of doing it:

- Use subdomains:

  - `*.dev.foobar.tld`
  - `*.staging.foobar.tld`
  - `*.foobar.tld`
- Use separate domains:

  - `*.foobar-dev.tld`
  - `*.foobar-staging.tld`
  - `*.foobar.tld`

I can see up and downs with both approaches, but I'm curious what the common practise is.

As a side-note, Cloudflare will not issue you certificates for sub-sub domains (e.g. `*.stage.foobar.tld`).

Comment: You can also use [`.test` domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test) (in addition to `example.com`). It is reserved for the purpose. `*.loc`, `*.dev` and `*.tld` (and friends) are not reserved and cannot be hijacked by the developer.

Comment: .corp is also suitable. It was almost a registrable TLD a few years ago until there was a huge stir about the fact that most enterprises use a .corp in the way you describe - which would break all those environments.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Depends on the company size.

Small businesses usually go for dashes and get the wildcard certificate.
So they would have `dev.example.com, test.example.com`

In larger enterprises they usually have a DNS infrastructure rolled out and the provisioning processes takes care of the assignment. It usually looks like

```
aws-eu-central-1.appName.staging.[teamName].example.com
```

They would either use their own self-signed certs with the CA on all servers or have the money for the SANs.

For more inspiration:

https://blog.serverdensity.com/server-naming-conventions-and-best-practices/

https://mnx.io/blog/a-proper-server-naming-scheme/

https://namingschemes.com/

Comment: The quote just made my day!

Comment: In a world with letsencrypt.org it's pretty easy to just allocate certs. If you're a web app, you want to think long and hard about cookie visibility and testing. As far as I can see, getting clever with internal DNS is a bad idea since it makes SAAS testing tools a lot more difficult to leverage.

Comment: @andrew IDD, but a lot of enterprises have ridiculous policies that prevent the use of Let's Encrypt, and instead insist on using a single, commercial CA

Comment: @Cocowalla AWS ACM isn't free, but it's dirt cheap and checks all the enterprise boxes. I think I'll double down on my position. Wildcard certs have huge blast radii and should be avoided like the plague that they are. Sharing the same dns root between prod and everything else is asking for problems.

Comment: @Andrew I wasn't arguing in favour of wildcard certs; my point was simply that Let's Encrypt makes cert allocation easy, especially in large orgs where the process to purchase *anything* is a nightmare

Answer (score 6):

we use below dns names in our environment

1. *.dev.internal.com ( development )
2. *.tst.internal.com ( test )
3. *.stg.internal.com ( staging )
4. *.internal.com ( prod ). you can also use like *.prd.internal.com

Answer (score 3):

A quick note about the top level domain, many companies also use the ".local" suffix for internal name resolution.

Answer (score 2):

It also depends if you want dev/test/staging be available externally, if not you can set in such way:
    app_name.example.dev, app_name.example.test and etc

Comment: And then you just ensure that your `hosts` file is updated on your local machine?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Yes.

Comment: You can use [`.test` domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test) (in addition to `example.com`). It is reserved for the purpose. `*.loc`, `*.dev` and `*.tld` (and friends) are not reserved and cannot be hijacked by the developer.

Answer (score -2):

.dev was acquired by Google; [you can use *.dev.cc](https://carnam.net/forever-dev-cc/) to point back to localhost.